# Why javascript is not loading for document.readyState==="complete"

Tags: javascript, html

I have just started learning javascript from [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_document_write) and I have found out that "You can only use document.write in the HTML output. If you use it after the document has loaded, the whole document will be overwritten." so I have tried to write following code to check the validity:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ashish javascript learning</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> sample html with javascript </p>
        <script>
            document.write("<h1>this is heading</h1>");
            document.write("<p>this is sample para</p>");
        </script>
        <script>
            if(document.readyState === "complete"){
                loaded();
            }
            function loaded(){
                document.write("<p>loading content after the document has been loaded");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code is still showing the old value and is not overwriting the content of the web page. Could you suggest me what am I doing wrongly.

Comment: Why are you using `document.write`?

Comment: @Ashish: One of the reliable JavaScript resources would be the [**JavaScript MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript) which has tons of links to good resources and guides.

Comment: Basically each of your `document.write` calls still happens during initial page creation. The `if` part will just evaluate to `false` and `loaded()` will never be called.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas 'cause of the terrible w3schools examples, I'd guess.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Thanks for the link. I will stop learning from w3 school and start learning for the link you have posted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At the time you're testing `document.readyState === "complete"`, the document's readyState *isn't* "complete", it "loading", so nothing happens, and `loaded` is never called.

You can listen for the readyState to change, and *then* check to see if it is "complete" (or listen to `window.onload` which is easier):

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', e => {
  if(document.readyState === "complete"){
    loaded();
  }
});
```

Comment: if my document is popup with pdf to download that is generated , the popup opens and its in complete ready state but the file is not loaded yet , can you advise thanks.

Comment: Avoid assigning value of `document.onreadystatechange`
Instead use `document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(evt) {})`

Answer (score 5):

Because the mechanism is event based. You should only ever use that once the DOM is actually loaded, so it's pointless.

The evaluation is done in place, but at the time of the evaluation `document.readyState == "complete"` is `false`, so nothing happens.

The simple way to do things:

```
window.onload = function() {
    loaded();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is hook a function to the [readystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/readystatechange) event *then* check for the `readystate` value.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        initApplication();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write like this ,you will get the result you want

```
document.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(document.readyState == 'complete'){
      document.write('document is overwrite')
   }
}
```

Comment: could you explain why? just giving an answer with no explanation whatsoever is not constructive, and does not answer the Why part of the question

Answer (score 0):

sorry for no explanation;
when the code execute on the javascript the dom is not completed ,so the document's readyState is not 'complete',then the initApplication funtion will not be called;
If you want to call the initApplication function,you have to add an trigger to the document.I add an trigger like 'document.onreadystatechange'."document.onreadystatechange" will be called when the document's state is changed;
so when the document is loaded ,the "document.onreadystatechange" will be called

Answer (score 0):

An excellent resource with multiple examples and explanations is:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

So in your case this applies:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    initApplication();
  }
}
```