# React. How to collect and transfer the collection of nodes as props to children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I try to collect the nodes after that the page are builded in the module `iteamsHolder`. It works for main `App` component and it see all collected iteams when I invoke the module `iteamsHolder` inside it.

But when I try to transfer the `iteamsHolder` module with iteams to children componennts of `App`, I have an `error` or `undefined` for this module iteams. So, I understand that the problem is in the component queue render. But how we can solve that error?

/* MAIN APP COMPONENT */

```
import iteamsHolder from '../view/iteamsHolder'
import sidebarWidgetHide from '../view/sidebarWidgetHide'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleKeyCode = this.handleKeyCode.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
 }


  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Preloader/>
        <LeftSideInfo state={this.state.toggle} updateState={this.updateState} 
             coordY={this.state.coordY}/>
        <MenuButtonOpen state={this.state.toggle} updateState={this.updateState} 
             iteamsHolder={iteamsHolder().iteamsMain}/> // this is where I'm 
                                    // trying to transfer the iteams module.
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
```

/* ITEAM HOLDER MODULE */

```
const iteamsHolder = () => {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {    
        let iteamsMain = {
            sidebar: document.querySelector('.left-side__column'),
            rightColumn: document.querySelector('.right-side__column')
        };

        let iteamsSupport = {
            header: document.querySelectorAll('.menu-button__container'),
            menuButton: document.querySelectorAll('.menu-button'),
            menuName: document.querySelector('.personal-name'),
            experienceblock: document.querySelector('.block-headline.block-headline__experience')
        }; 

        return { iteamsMain, iteamsSupport };
    } else {
        return 'Sorry';
    }

};

export default iteamsHolder;
```

/CHILD COMPONENT WITH NESTED ITEAMS MODULE/

```
class MenuButtonOpen extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
}

render() {
    return ( 
    {console.log(this.props.iteamsHolder)} // undefined of error
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `undefined` because `iteamsHolder` is returning the default value `'Sorry'`, not the object `{ iteamsMain, iteamsSupport }`. If you change is to:

```
<MenuButtonOpen
  state={this.state.toggle}
  updateState={this.updateState}
  iteamsHolder={iteamsHolder()}
/>
```

you'll see that `'Sorry'` is being passed to the component. This is because when `iteamsHolder` is being evaluated, the webpage is not yet fully loaded. Without knowing why you've structured your code the way you did, I can't make a good suggestion on how to "fix" it. What may help is looking at how `document.readyState` works and reading through [suggestions like what's listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450973/why-javascript-is-not-loading-for-document-readystate-complete).